How to integrate Salesforce with JIRA?
I try to find few documentations from JIRA, still looking for a easy way to connect from salesforce to JIRA.
In tried few app exchange packages which can able to connect only with standard objects but my use case is to connect custom object with salesforce JIRA issue.
Please suggest some easy options to integrate salesforce with JIRA.

If you cannot find an open-source or 3rd party app that meets your needs, you will have to research  Jira's webhook and API features and build your own integration.

Your question is quite broad, I'd recommend you put some more effort into reading below options.

Custom API Integration: You can use the JIRA REST API to integrate directly with Salesforce. This approach provides flexibility to connect custom objects and tailor the solution which you are expecting.
Corn: Learning Curve for understanding and implementing might be difficult if you are not a Salesforce developer.

AppExchange Packages with Customization
You have already mentioned that you have tried some appexchange packages, have you tried to check with them for customization of the app? It's your easy way to get connected to Jira without complex development.


When I check in AppExchange I could see ADL Connect app has the capability to connect with Custom object have you tried it?

Thanks for your reply, I will try and get back.

Thank you for sharing this app ADL Connect, This app is exactly what we've been looking for, The best part is that it's free with certain limits, However, it a great fit for our needs. You saved us from lot of effort and time.

If you don't want to pay license cost to thirs party tools or it doesn't fit your requirement, You can use this to start with your implementation:-

The method expect you to pass username of jira integration user
You need to create access token and pass
also you need to know jira base url

Apex
public class JiraIntegrationService {
    private static String getBasicAuth(String userName, String apiToken) {
        String authString = userName + ':' + apiToken;
        return 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(authString));
    }

    @auraEnabled
    public static String createJiraIssue(String userName, String apiToken, String baseUrl, String requestBody) {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(baseUrl + '/rest/api/3/issue');        
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', getBasicAuth(userName,apiToken));
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setBody(requestBody);
        
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
        
        if (res.getStatusCode() == 201) {
            Map<String, Object> responseMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
            return '' + responseMap.get('key');
        } else {
            return 'Something went wrong';
        }
    }
}

I have tried for creating an item in jira from lwc, You can find postman collection for all kind of jira request here: https://www.postman.com/api-evangelist/atlassian-jira/overview
LWC JS code here:
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import createJiraIssue from '@salesforce/apex/JiraIntegrationService.createJiraIssue';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class CreateJiraItem extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    //replace these values according to your jira account
    @api jiraProjectKey = 'your project key from Jira';
    @api jiraUserName = 'your jira username';
    @api jiraApiToken = 'your access token created in jira';
    @api jiraBaseUrl = 'your base url of jira';
    summary = '';
    description = '';
    jiraResponseId = '';
    showSpinner;

    get requestBody() {
        return {
            "fields": {
                "project": {
                    "key": this.jiraProjectKey
                },
                "summary": this.summary,
                "description": {
                    "type": "doc",
                    "version": 1,
                    "content": [
                        {
                            "type": "paragraph",
                            "content": [
                                {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "text": this.description
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "issuetype": {
                    "name": "Task"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    async handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const formFields = event.detail.fields;
        this.showSpinner = true;
        this.summary = formFields.summary__c;
        this.description = formFields.Description__c;
        try {
            this.jiraResponseId = await createJiraIssue({
                userName: this.jiraUserName,
                apiToken: this.jiraApiToken,
                baseUrl: this.jiraBaseUrl,
                requestBody: JSON.stringify(this.requestBody)
            });
        } catch (error) {
            this.jiraResponseId = '';
        }
        this.showSpinner = false;
    }
}

Read more in detail here:https://salesforcediaries.com/2024/06/11/create-jira-issues-from-lwc-in-salesforce/

Our architect team has rejected this approach as Basic authentication is going to deprecated soon by JIRA.
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/basic-auth-for-rest-apis/

You can change the authentication mechanism. The answer just shown you a way how you can achieve this in custom way.
